# Base class for managing factory classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, dry, code-reuse

I have a StaffFactory for getting Staff objects by various means, but I also have some setup methods to determine which data source to use.

```
class StaffFactory
{
    private const string DefaultDbSourceName = "Production";
    private string dbSourceName;
    #region Factory Management
    private static Dictionary<string, StaffFactory> staffFactories = new Dictionary<string,StaffFactory>();
    public static StaffFactory GetInstance()
    {
        return GetInstance(DefaultDbSourceName);
    }
    public static StaffFactory GetInstance(string dbSourceName)
    {
        if (!staffFactories.ContainsKey(dbSourceName))
        {
            staffFactories.Add(dbSourceName, new StaffFactory(dbSourceName));
        }
        return staffFactories[dbSourceName];
    }
    private StaffFactory(string dbSourceName)
    {
        this.dbSourceName = dbSourceName;
    }
    #endregion Factory Management
    #region Factory Methods
    public Staff ById(int id) { ... }
    public IList<Staff> ByName(string name) { ... }
    ...
    #endregion Factory Methods
}
```

As I go to create my next factory, I realise all this management logic is going to remain the same regardless of what type the factory is for. So I'm thinking I create some base Factory or Factory class that houses that logic, and then my declare the above with `class StaffFactory : Factory<Staff> { ... }` or something, but I'm drawing complete blanks on how I would go about that. Whether or not to implement it using generics, etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: are you trying to implement a Factory, Singelton or Repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you introduce a new abstraction layer, make sure that the benefits will outweigh the costs. In your case, those would include:

**The cost to design and implement the abstraction**

StaffFactory is much easier to design, implement and test than a generic Factory<T> class.

**The cost to understand the Factory<T> abstraction**

Every time someone reads the code, they may need to wrap their head around the abstraction. A generic abstraction is harder to wrap your head around than a non-generic one.

**The cost to make changes in the future**

Let's say that you have Factory<Staff> and Factory<Product>, and in the future you find that you want a different caching policy for the two. Maybe the Factory<Product> should discard the cached object if the cache size exceeds some threshold.

Are you going to generalize the Factory<> class to support different modes? That can be done, but its much more complex than just modifying StaffFactory and ProductFactory classes independently.

**Summary**

So, don't introduce an abstraction just for the sake of it. And, definitely do not generalize StaffFactory into a generic Factory<T> if Factory<Staff> is going to be the only generic instantiation you'll have.

From your code above, it seems that your Factory<T> class would be basically a Dictionary<string, T>. If that's the case, then introducing the additional generic Factory class does not get you much benefit and only adds an unnecessary abstraction layer.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I think the Factory<T> class would be a Dictionary<type, Dictionary<string, T>>, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you're going to implement is a Repository pattern. See the answers to [Repository pattern tutorial in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c-sharp).